# Background with URL

Tags: jquery, css

How can I set as a default image a gif, via css.

I'm trying to put this (the gif exist in my project), but returns an error. URL undefined.

```
background: url('..tema/default/images/loadingvenda.gif')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
background: url('../tema/default/images/loadingvenda.gif')
```

Comment: Don't forget the `;` if you're going to add more stuff

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the wrong relative URL (cannot do `..` in a word):

```
background: url('..tema/default/images/loadingvenda.gif')
```

should be something like:

```
background: url('../tema/default/images/loadingvenda.gif')
```

Notice the `../tema/`